# Bom, eu clico nisso sem clicar mais em nd e fuciona perfeito, mas se eu clico em outro lugar da tela e clico no botão de mudar arma o game n reconhece

Tags: java, android

public class HudManager {
public Activity activity;
public ConstraintLayout hud_layout;

```
private final NvEventQueueActivity mContext = null;

public TextView hud_money;

public ImageView hud_weapon;

public ImageView hud_radar;

public ImageView hud_x2;

public ImageView hud_menu;
public ImageView hud_micro;

public ImageView hud_gps;

public ImageView hud_zona;

public ArrayList<ImageView> hud_wanted;

public ProgressBar progressHP;
public ProgressBar progressArmor;

public HudManager(Activity aactivity) {
    activity = aactivity;
    hud_layout = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_main);
    hud_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    progressArmor = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_armor_pb);
    progressHP = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_health_pb);

    hud_radar = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.radar_hude);

    hud_micro = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView14);

    hud_gps = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
    hud_zona = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.grzona);
    hud_x2 = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView17);

    hud_money = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_money);
    hud_weapon = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_weapon);
    hud_menu = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.hud_menu);

    hud_wanted = new ArrayList<>();
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_1));
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_2));
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_3));
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_4));
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_5));
    hud_wanted.add(activity.findViewById(R.id.hud_star_6));
    hud_micro.setOnClickListener( view -> {
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(aactivity, R.anim.button_click));
    });

    hud_menu.setOnClickListener( view -> {
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(aactivity, R.anim.button_click));
        NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().showMenu();
        NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().togglePlayer(1);
    });
}

public void UpdateHudInfo(int health, int armour, int hunger, int weaponidweik, int ammo, int playerid, int money, int wanted)
{
    progressHP.setProgress(health);
    progressArmor.setProgress(armour);

    DecimalFormat formatter=new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols= DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    String s= formatter.format(money);
    hud_money.setText(s);

    int id = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(new Formatter().format("weapon_%d", Integer.valueOf(weaponidweik)).toString(), "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
    hud_weapon.setImageResource(id);

    hud_weapon.setOnClickListener(v -> NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().onWeaponChanged());
    if(wanted > 6) wanted = 6;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < wanted; i2++) {
        hud_wanted.get(i2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_y_star);
    }

    //Toast.makeText(aactivity, "X:" + (int)hud_radar.getX() + " Y:" + (int)hud_radar.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //System by Weikton, ALL REVERS: F*UCK YOU
   // NvEventQueueActivity.setNativeHudElementPosition(6, (int)hud_radar.getX(), (int)hud_radar.getY());
   // NvEventQueueActivity.setNativeHudElementScale(6, (int)hud_radar.getX(), (int)hud_radar.getY())/*, (int)hud_radar.getScaleType()*/;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.